# How to get drush to list ONLY parent folders on module list command?

Tags: drush

I use this command to get a list of contrib enabled modules:

```
drush pm-list --type=module --status=enabled --no-core --format=list
```

Problem is, it also lists submodules, for example:

```
admin_menu
admin_menu_toolbar
```

So if I use this to reinstall the modules on another site:

```
Drush dl admin_menu admin_menu_toolbar
```

It causes errors. So I need to drush only:

```
Drush dl admin_menu
```

So how can I get the list of ONLY parent modules?

My goal is to get drush to display list of modules on the source site, but only folder names, not subfolders

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the pm-projectinfo command.  See: http://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/pm/pm-projectinfo/

In Drupal, "projects" contain "extensions". An "extension" can be either a module or a theme.  `drush pm-list` will show a list of modules and themes; `drush pm-projectinfo` shows a list of projects.

*UPDATE:* If you want to convert an existing site into a reproducible, buildable script, you might also be interested in using Composer.  See https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project and https://www.drupal.org/project/composer_generate

Comment: That IS what I am using actually, but I need the parent modules, list, WITHOUT the subfolders...is there a folder list command? If I have 2 folders, A and B, a contains folder 1,2 and B contains folder 3,4 , I want the list as folder A,B, not A,1,2,B,3,4

Comment: In your original question, you said you were using `pm-list`. I suggest you try `pm-projectinfo`.  In particular, `drush pm-projectinfo --format=list --fields=path`.

Answer (score 1):

When installing the modules, if you use "drush pm-enable ..." ("drush en ..." for short) drush will sort out the dependencies for you and just download the ones you need.

http://drushcommands.com/drush-7x/pm/pm-enable/

Comment: Yes this will work, however, i need the list WITHOUT dependencies first, repopulating is not the problem. I am trying to get the list of parent modules, without the dependencies. The same thing one can see when viewing modules in Windows Explorer

Comment: But if, as you say, you are trying to reinstalling on another site, and you use drush en, you do not need this list. If you need it for another reason perhaps you should edit your question to make that clearer?

Comment: I edited the question, it's about fetching modules list, not reinstalling

Comment: Why not use a make file instead? Drush will both create and consume the same file, and only "main" modules will be included

Comment: @BrunoVincent it's still not clear to me why you want the list of modules. What are you planning to do with it if not to reinstall on another site? It's always a good idea to state the underlying problem you are trying to solve - that way you may get a better answer.

Comment: Reinstall on other site yes, without drush make, just the list of enabled contib modules, parent folder name only, not child folders

Comment: If that's what you are trying to achieve then what's wrong with drush en and not worrying about which are parent modules? You are going to need to enable the submodules anyway. (By the way, this sounds like a job for the features module.)

Comment: Because the list it provide me includes submodules, and when reinstalling it creates errors, you can only use parent modules list that doesn't include submodules for this to work, hard to explain I guess...

Comment: Note that pm-enable cannot find a project name given a module name; it will try to download the project with the same name as the module, but this is the only working variant at the moment. Most sites have some enabled modules with names that are different than the project that contains them.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have high enough reputation to comment on Greg's, I post a new answer - which is a minor improvement to Greg's answer:

```
drush pm-projectinfo --format=list --fields=x,y --status=enabled
```

This works because the list format returns the array key if multiple fields are selected - no matter what the fields are called ;-) The benefit of this compared to just listing the directory content is that you can use the status filter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found a solution. If someone can add how to do this with Drush it would be great, but not sure if possible...

I use the command prompt in Windows 7:

```
C:\layouts\sites\all\modules
```

Then:

```
 DIR /B C:\layouts\sites\all\modules
```

This gives me a very clear, clean list of modules WITHOUT subfolders.

I can then use this list to repopulate sites without errors.